# iPhone Airdrop can't find Macbook, but Macbook can find and airdrop to iPhone

Tags: iphone, airdrop

I'm so stumped here. About 6 or so months ago, my iPhone stopped recognizing my 2012 Macbook Pro running High Sierra, and my work Macbook Pro 2013 now running Mojave. I recently got a new iPhone Xs Max and thought this would fix it, but still same issue. It's so odd, both Macbooks can detect the iPhone and transfer files to it, but not the other way around. iPhone can detect other laptops and share files just not mine.

Here's everything I've tried to troubleshoot:

- Restarting both iPhone and Macbook
- Reset network settings on iPhone
- Airdrop on both set to Everyone
- Signed in and out of iCloud on all devices
- Put both on same wifi network
- Used terminal to kill bluetooth
- Went into preferences and deleted `com.apple.Bluetooth.plist`
- Reset pram on macbook
- Went into security and privacy > firewall on macbook and unchecked block all incoming transfers (as well as just turned off firewall)
- Hotspot turned off on iPhone

No idea what's going on, feel like I'm going crazy :) thanks in advance for any tips or thoughts!

Comment: After killing BT using the MacBook's Terminal, did you turn it on again?